# Magento 1.9 : How to create our own custom timezone?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, timezone

I want to create my own custom timezome in magento at

`System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Timezone`.

Can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your timezone manually 
first go to :
`app/etc/config.xml` and add your time zone here

```
        <general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_US</code>
                <timezone>Asia/Calcutta</timezone>
            </locale>
        </general>
```

Now go to `app/Mage.php` on line `768`
and change this line too

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`
to your `timezone`
`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`

EDIT1:
Try this http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-setup-configure-manage-time-zones-in-magento/

Comment: I don't want this. I want to create a new option like `custom timezone` in that dropdown

Comment: I edited my post